# Do MutationObservers Only Listen To Local Changes?

Tags: javascript, mutation-observers

I wanted to use MutationObservers to listen for a specific class addition (step_active) to elements with a class of (step), however this doesn't seem to be firing quite as expected.

If I add the class directly via **element.classList.add()** my event fires. When the site issues these class changes itself however - my events are **not** fired.

Why is this?

Here is the general format of my current code:

```
var target = document.querySelectorAll(".step");
for (var i = 0; i < target.length; i++) {
    var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
        mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {
            var trigger = mutation.target;
            if(trigger.classList.contains('step_active')){
              window.dataLayer.push({
                event: 'Step: ' + mutation.id
              });
            }
        })
    });
    var config = {attributes: true, childList: true, subtree: true};
    observer.observe(target[i], config);
};
```

I expected this to push a unique event with the mutation.id as I progress through the steps on the page - This is not the case however. Instead doing something like this does produce the event I was expecting:

```
setTimeout(function(){
target[0].classList.add('step_active');
}, 1000);
```

Can anyone shed some light on what I'm missing/have misunderstood here?

Comment: It simply means the site replaces the target element (or its parent higher up the tree) so your observer isn't notified because the old element is no longer in the actual DOM.

Comment: Ah - right you are. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out by wOxxOm this was caused by the elements that I was observing being replaced rather than manipulated, thus breaking my mutation observer.

1. This scenario can be tested by artificially adding a class and
   observing whether it is retained as you progress.
2. Or setting the MutationObserver to a higher level within the DOM and logging 
   the mutationRecord.